# How to make a RibbonSplitButton open its dropdown list when clicked?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I'm using RibbonSplitButton of the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF and want to open its dropdown when clicked. I tried to catched the clicked button and set IsDropDownOpen=true but the dropdown open then close immediately. How can I retain the dropdown open?

[Edit]
Here is [my demo codes](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/MicrosoftRibbonForWPFSourceAndSamples.rar) to reproduce my problem - I modified the Word sample in the sample downloaded from [MSDN's WPF Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx).
My split-button is placed in the file UserControlWord.xaml and located right after the comment

I added a handler for the click event and set the property IsDropDownOpen to true expecting to open the dropdown but it doesn't - the problem appears as I posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change my demo button to this type [RibbonMenuButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonmenubutton(v=vs.110).aspx) will fix the problem.